# Is it possible to get instance of a class 2 where constructor of class 1 was called?

Tags: java, oop

Lets imagine this situation: we have Class1 and Class2

```
public class Class1 {
    private Class2 field;
    public Class1() {}
    public doStuff() {
         this.field = new Class2();
    }
}
public class Class2 {
    public Class2() {} //get Class1 instance that has called this method
}
```

I want to know if it is possible to get Class1 instance in Class2 constructor somehow.
I've been thinking about viewing a stack trace but it looks like a bad way

Comment: You want the pizza constructor to construct a sandwich when called. Do you think that's possible? What is the practicality of this? If the pizza constructor construct a sandwich, how would you then construct a pizza? What does the sandwich constructor construct?

Comment: This is impossible, @Notlimitedwolf. Stack Trace just gives you 'Class1', it doesn't give you _the instance_.

Comment: @hfontanez You have missed the idea. I do not want to create another instance of Class1, I just want to get the one that called it. Better example with human and sandwich: I don't want sandwich to create new human, I just want sandwich to know its creator without passing it into parameters

Comment: @Notlimitedwolf The relationship (in Java) between an object instance and the creator (the entity calling the constructor) is not preserved. You must do this yourself if it is important to you. Because you need to establish it, it cannot be done without passing some kind of parameter.

Comment: @hfontanez a solution by daniu was exactly the one that I was looking for. It obtains Class1 and provides an ability to get some fields

Comment: @Notlimitedwolf Perhaps you need to read the comment I posted there. The association between "Human" and "Sandwich" is technically speaking NOT what you requested. There is a reason why in UML there's no "created by" relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `Class2` always seems to require a `Class1` object, this might be a pretty good case for an inner class.

```
public class Class1 {
    private Class2 field;
    public doStuff() {
         this.field = new Class2();
    }

    // Class2 is an inner class of Class1
    public class Class2 {
        public Class1 getCreatingClass1Instance() {
           return Class1.this;
        }
    }
}
```

Whether this actually makes sense for you depends on the context. Your "get the `Human` that made the `Sandwich` is not one.

Comment: Technically speaking, the relationship between the outer and inner class is "ownership", a `Human` has-a `Sandwich`. It just so happened that this `Human` was (coincidentally) the one who made it.

Answer (score 3):

If you really need the instance of `Class1`, and not just the class name, then the only way would be something like this:

In `Class1`:

```
public doStuff() {
    this.field = new Class2(this);
}
```

In `Class2`:

```
public Class2(Class1 instance) {
    // do whatever you need with the Class1 instance)
}
```

Comment: That's sad that i have to pass it into params. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Notlimitedwolf The other option is to have the language define another implicit parameter in every constructor ever created that references the "calling instance".  All you would ever know about this instance, however, is that it'd be an `Object`, because the constructor can be called from an instance of any type. And then you have to worry about if the class was instantiated from a static context (i.e., no "calling instance"). Maybe another language does this, but that seems strange and confusing to me.